# How to reverse margin of tufte-book?

Tags: double-sided, marginpar, tufte

I want to change position of `tufte-book(twoside)` class in my thesis. In normal mode, margins for odd pages is on the right side and for evens, is on the left side of page. I want to change the position of margins.

Normal:
[image]

Reverse:
[image]

Comment: Try `\let\OldOddSideMargin\oddsidemargin
\let\oddsidemargin\evensidemargin
\let\evensidemargin\OldOddSideMargin`.  This works with `book` class, but I can't seem to get a two sided output with `tufte-book`.

Comment: Oh, you'll probably also need `\reversemarginpar`.

Comment: No, this is not working. :-(

Comment: Like I said I was not able to get two sided output with `tufte-book` class so perhaps there is something special about that class that I am not aware of. It really would be helpful if you posted a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that set up the problem.

Comment: May I know the title of the book from which you took the screenshot?

Answer (score 3):

Is your thesis written in an RTL language?  if it is and assumning, `twoside` option is used and `bidi` package is loaded, then `bidi` package takes care of this and puts margins in RTL mode in odd pages on LHS and in RTL mode in even pages, it puts margins on the RHS. Here is an example:

```
....
\usepackage{ptext}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\begin{document}
\ptext[1]
\begin{marginfigure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{demo}
\caption{این یک شکل است}
\end{marginfigure}
\ptext
\end{document}
```

and here is the output:

[image]

And the same example using `bidi` package and latin characters:

```
...
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[RTLdocument]{bidi}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{marginfigure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{demo}
\caption{This is a figure}
\end{marginfigure}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is `xepersian` package crucial to solve the problem?

Comment: No `bidi` is crucial.

Comment: So where is `bidi` in your code?

Comment: `xepersian` loads `bidi` package automatically.

Comment: Why don't you make the solution useful for more users? I cannot compile it with `pdflatex`.

Comment: Because `bidi` package only supports `xetex`. I could add support for `pdflatex` too only if I was paid to do.

Comment: Is it only for persian? I could not use it with latin characters.

Comment: No, I updated my answer to use only `bidi` package. It works with any RTL language.